# How to add another fragment into ViewPager2?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewpager2

I'm trying to add more fragments dynamically inside my ViewPager2 however when I call the `adapter.add(MyNewFragment, position)` 2 things happens, if I use `notifyDataSetChange()` is not showing up the fragment but if I put `notifyItemInserted(position)` is showing up but the app crashes with an `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added`.

This is my adapter class:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(
    list: MutableList<Fragment>,
    fm: FragmentManager,
    lifecycle: Lifecycle,
    //fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity
) : FragmentStateAdapter(fm, lifecycle) {

    var fragmentList = list

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return fragmentList.size
    }

    fun addScreen(fragment: Fragment, position: Int) {
        if(!fragmentList.contains(fragment)){
            fragmentList.add(position, fragment)
            //notifyItemInserted(position)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragmentList[position]
    }


    // I tried to use these methods that I saw here but then the viewpager is totally blank and does not load anything or do the same Fragment already added error.

   /* override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return fragmentList[position].id.toLong()
    }

    override fun containsItem(itemId: Long): Boolean = fragmentList.any { it.id.toLong() == itemId }*/
}
```

And this is my the screen where the viewPager is:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ViewPagerScreen : Fragment() {

    //...


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        if (!::savedViewInstance.isInitialized) {
            _binding = FragmentViewPagerScreenBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

            //....
            savedViewInstance = binding.root
        }

        binding.viewPager.isSaveEnabled = false

        return savedViewInstance
    }


    fun addNewScreen(){
        adapter.addScreen(NewFragment(), binding.viewPager.currentItem + 1)
    }

    private fun initViewPager() {
        binding.viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 2
        binding.viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            override fun onPageScrolled(
                position: Int,
                positionOffset: Float,
                positionOffsetPixels: Int
            ) {
                super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels)
            }
        })

        adapter = ViewPagerAdapterByFragments(
            mutableListOf(FirstScreen(), SecondScreen(), ThirdScreen()),
            this@ViewPagerScreen.childFragmentManager,
            lifecycle
        )
        binding.viewPager.adapter = adapter

        binding.viewPager.isUserInputEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Comment: inside `createFragment` method you aren't creating NEW fragment, you are providing existing one from array. try to write this method properly, create new fragment in this method straightly

Comment: Thanks so much!! Now it's working like a charm :D

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem, thanks *@snachmsm* for pointing me out where to look for.

What I did was quite simple, I only had to change the param `list: MutableList<Fragment>` to `list:MutableList<Pair<String,Fragment>>` where my  `String` is my `fragmentId`. Then on the method `createFragment` return a new fragment base on my `fragmentId`.

Here's the code itself:

```
override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (fragmentList!![position]!!.first) {
            "firstScreen" -> return FirstScreen()
            "secondScreen" ->return SecondScreen()
            "thirdScreen" ->return ThirdScreen()
            "newScreen" -> return NewScreen()
            else -> AnotherScreen()
        }
    }
```

Also my `addScreenMethod()` now looks like this:

```
fun addScreen(newfragment: Pair<String, Fragment>, position: Int) {
        val result = fragmentList.find {
            it.first == newfragment.first
        }
 
        if (result == null) {
            fragmentList.add(position, newfragment)
            notifyItemInserted(position)
        }
}
```